# Webmatrix query helper and multiple result sets

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

Does the query helper have the ability to return multiple datasets from a stored procedure? I've checked around online and have not found much info on the query helper. Is this a task for straight ADO instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use straight ADO.NET for this. The WebMatrix.Data.Database class offers no support for multiple resultsets.